# Why do I keep getting error message for last line of code?

Tags: php, mime, mailer

When I run this I get the following error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in W:\xampp\htdocs___\phpmail.php on line 85

```
<?php
 // Setting a timezone, mail() uses this.
 date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
  // recipients
 $to  = "you@phpeveryday.com" . ", " ; // note the comma 
 $to .= "we@phpeveryday.com"; 

  // subject 
 $subject = "Test for Embedded Image & Attachement"; 

 // Create a boundary string.  It needs to be unique 
 $sep = sha1(date('r', time()));

 // Add in our content boundary, and mime type specification:  
 $headers .=
    "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; 
     boundary=\"PHP-mixed-{$sep}\"";

 // Read in our file attachment
 $attachment = file_get_contents('attachment.zip');
 $encoded = base64_encode($attachment);
 $attached = chunk_split($encoded);

 // additional headers
 $headers .= "To: You <you@phpeveryday.com>, 
             We <we@phpeveryday.com>\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "From: Me <me@phpeveryday.com>\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "Cc: he@phpeveryday.com\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "Bcc: she@phpeveryday.com\r\n";

 $inline = chunk_split(base64_encode(
           file_get_contents('mypicture.gif')));

 // Your message here:
 $body =<<<EOBODY
 --PHP-mixed-{$sep}
 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
               boundary="PHP-alt-{$sep}"

 --PHP-alt-{$sep}
 Content-Type: text/plain

 Hai, It's me!


 --PHP-alt-{$sep}
 Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="PHP-related-{$sep}"
,
 --PHP-alt-{$sep}
 Content-Type: text/html

 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Test HTML Mail</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <font color='red'>Hai, it is me!</font>
 Here is my picture: 
  <img src="cid:PHP-CID-{$sep}" />
 </body>
 </html>

 --PHP-related-{$sep}
 Content-Type: image/gif
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
 Content-ID: <PHP-CID-{$sep}> 

 {$inline}
 --PHP-related-{$sep}--

 --PHP-alt-{$sep}--

 --PHP-mixed-{$sep}
 Content-Type: application/zip; name="attachment.zip"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
 Content-Disposition: attachment

 {$attached}

 --PHP-mixed-{$sep}--
 EOBODY;

 // Finally, send the email
 mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
 ?>
```

Why Is it that i get this error? I got this code from a tutorial here:  www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Email-Using-Embedded-Images-in-HTML-Email-P113.html

Comment: check this line no and fix quoting

Comment: You're not ending the HEREDOC correctly. There should be no whitespace before `EBODY` on that line. You should [enable error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393) to see that kind of useful error messages.

Comment: Have you read comments to this tutorial? They screw it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your mail function is still in EOBODY.

Also please try to find another solution, or create your own mailer, because i've just read some comments in this page:

- I think this must be one of the worst tutorials ever, doesn't work
- this is a stupid shit.
- u idiot

etc... and i agree.

There are much more good tutorial like this. Use PHPMailer.

Comment: Thanks, And yeah you're right. The tutorial is aweful.